# How can I store multiple geometries created inside repeat zone as instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm working on a Blender-to-gcode project. I've created the randomized shape generator and now I'm trying to put it inside a repeat zone to quickly generate multiple shapes.

I want to store each iteration as an instance to control the way I distribute them on a grid, for example.

My problem is that each iteration is stacked on the previous one. How can I separate them?

[image: The setup is fairly easy...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is convert the geometry created in the repeat zone into an instance and then add it to the existing geometry with `Join Geometry`.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried doing that but i simply forgot to check "pick instance afterwards"... You're still a lifesaver i was running in circles XD